# Шрифт не работает

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, шрифты

[image: у меня же main.css находится css][image: текс должен быть написан как на логотипе в файле svg]

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Blinker', 'wght@900' ;
    color: 000;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Taxisite</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Blinker:wght@900&family=Inter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

---

если я правильно понял, то это должно выглядеть вот так, но это не работает[[image: вот так?][1]]

Comment: Наверное было бы неплохо добавить неких подробностей. Смотря на то что есть, font-family должен быть `font-family: 'Blinker';` или `font-family: 'Blinker', sans-serif;`, вот этого `'wght@900'` там быть не должно. Когда задаете цвет в HEX, он должен быть `color: #000;`, а не просто `color: 000;`.

Comment: ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">```

Comment: пожалуйста, не прикладывайте код скришотом

Comment: @Tikhon, используйте ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">``` и посмотрите на результат. Картинки не имеет смысла прикладывать.

Comment: @void, я прикрепил изображение и у меня же вроде всё правильно

Comment: ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">``` - это не ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">```

Answer (score 0):

Это потому, что ваш файл main.css не находится там, куда указывает href="css/main.css". Если ваш HTML-файл находится в корневой директории, то mian.css должен находиться в директории css. Т.е. выглядеть иерархия должна так:

```
C:\tmp>dir /s

 Directory of C:\tmp

2022-08-29  23:45    <DIR>          .
2022-08-29  23:45    <DIR>          css
2022-08-29  23:40               529 index.html
               1 File(s)            529 bytes

 Directory of C:\tmp\css

2022-08-29  23:45    <DIR>          .
2022-08-29  23:45    <DIR>          ..
2022-08-29  23:42               122 main.css
               1 File(s)            122 bytes
```

Т.е. в корневой лежит index.html, здесь же есть директория ccs, в которой должен находиться ваш main.css

UPD: учитывая вашу "картинку", ваш index.html лежит в директории wwp. Стало быть, вам в index.html надо использовать

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
```

Ну и исправить ошибки в CSS тоже неплохо было бы, как посоветовали в комментарии выше.